# Android RevenueCat Error 520 on /receipts POST

Tags: android, in-app-billing, revenuecat

I am developing billing using RevenueCat. I am getting an 520 error on POST to /receipts after a purchase is completed. Google Play shows window of purchase completed but 5 minutes after I recieve an email of cancellation. These are the logs of the error:

```
[Purchases] - WARN W  ⚠️ Unable to start a network connection due to a network configuration issue: https://api.revenuecat.com/v1/receipts
[Purchases] - DEBUG D  ℹ️ API request started: POST /receipts
[Purchases] - DEBUG D  ℹ️ API request completed with status: POST /receipts 520
[Purchases] - ERROR E  ‼️ There was a problem with the store.
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears when you don't have allowed [Google Play Android Developer API](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/androidpublisher.googleapis.com?q=search&referrer=search) on your Google Cloud Platform project